# English Dictionary Patentability

Tags: dictionary

Can a new English dictionary be patented?

If so, can it be patented as an article of manufacture?

What category would it fall into?

Answer (score 1):

No. An English dictionary is not a novel invention. They've been around for quite some time.

Moreover, simply changing the words or definitions does not provide a patentable difference, as textual matter is not patent-eligible.

As an aside, a new dictionary would likely be covered by copyright. But that is off-topic here.

Comment: "as an article of manufacture" - well, in theory .. :P

Comment: A book with a newly invented binding would be an article of manufacture.  A strange triangular shaped book might be covered by a design patent. There is a "printed matter doctrine" that says that the content of printed matter can't be what makes an invention different from the past. (It is more complicated - but no dictionary.